# Add a Row in a table in specific position and merged

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following table and want to add a new row betweewn rows 2 and 3 with merged cells, this is my code so far.

```js
$("#table tr:nth-child(3)").append("<tr><td>ee</td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>bb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td>dd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my fiddle example I'm working on
[Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/b4xhG/3/)

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` will add the row as a *child* of the targeted element, thus you'll have nested a `<tr>` within a `<tr>`.

I believe what you want instead is to put the new row [`.before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/) the selected row. If you want the cell to expand the entire width of the table, give the `<td>` a [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) value equal to the amount of columns.

```js
$("#table tr:nth-child(3)").before("<tr><td colspan='3'>ee</td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>aa</td>
      <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>bb</td>
      <td>bb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>cc</td>
      <td>cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td>dd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```